# Using Xcode 4.4 build mac apps for Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mountain-lion

Newbie question I know... But can I build apps for Snow Leopard using the Mountain Lion Version of Xcode 4.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can always build programs with an intended target version of less than the current version (as long as that older version is still supported).

Comment: To further clarify, set the project's deployment target to 10.6. As long as you don't use any methods added in 10.7 or later, your app will run on 10.6.